# Nordvpn does not work on UBUNTU

Tags: networking, 18.04, vpn

I have problems with connecting to Nordvpn on my Ubuntu 18.04.02.LTS since 3 days.
I am using terminal to connect to servers. When I try to connect to one of server I receive information:

```
Whoops! We couldn't connect you to 'de'. Please try again. If the problem persists, contact our customer support.
```

I have done all updates, I tried to reinstall Nordvpn unfortunatelly nothing helps. Problem persists only when I am trying to connect by terminal.
I can connect using Network Manager(I am not using that because after 20 minutes my connection drops)

Comment: Try `apt purge nordvpn` and then reinstall to get rid of some old configuration. You can also try another country.

Comment: Did you report this to the "Paid" VPN Service?

Comment: @pLumo I will try it after work, thank you for tip

Comment: @EODCraftStaff not yet I will do it also but I know what they will write to me 'try update, if does not help use Network Manager'

Comment: Then I would ask for a refund and take my business elsewhere, like PIA!

Comment: FWIW, I am using NordVPN just fine for a year now on Ubuntu 18.04. That error message you show looks fishy quoting it can't connect to "de". I would expect it to quote a full server name like "de103.nordvpn.com". What command line exactly are you using to connect?

Comment: I have the same problem, it seems after an update Nordvpn terminal app will not work. It works with network manager fine, but it will not connect on start up like it did before, so you end up browsing unprotected. Very frustrating. I had to do a new system install to get it working, but just now it stopped again. Their Linux support is very bad. I have tried everything. ubuntu studio 19.04

Comment: I can only recommend using Network Manager or directly openvpn from a console with their configuration files to connect, which may also give you a hint what exactly doesn't work in the output log. If it doesn't connect, update the config files or try to change the server, sometimes servers go down.

Comment: I have solved problem thanks to @pLumo, what I did was:
`sudo apt purge nordvpn`, but I have noticed that not all files has been deleted. In a path `/var/lib/nordvpn/data/` I have removed .config.ovpn with `sudo rm -R .config.ovpn` (I had to change permisions before)

Comment: Great! So please go ahead and write an answer with your steps. You can later accept it, it may help other users.

Comment: Visit https://support.nordvpn.com/ this suport!
<https://support.nordvpn.com/Connectivity/Linux/1322207652/Troubleshooting-connectivity-Linux.htm>?
follow this instruction.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
nordvpn logout && sudo chattr -i -a /var/lib/nordvpn/data/.config.ovpn \ 
&& sudo chmod ugo+w /var/lib/nordvpn/data/.config.ovpn && nordvpn login \ 
&& nordvpn connect
```

Answer (score 0):

> First I purged `nordvpn` by running
>
> ```
> sudo apt purge nordvpn
> ```
>
> but I have noticed that not all files has been deleted. In the path `/var/lib/nordvpn/data/` I have removed
>   `.config.ovpn` with
>
> ```
> sudo rm -R .config.ovpn
> ```
>
> (I had to change permissions before).

---

Source: [comment by OP](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1160341/nordvpn-does-not-work-on-ubuntu#comment1933417_1160341)

Answer (score 0):

This problem comes up periodically with nordvpn updates. It has happened to me four or five times in the last year alone. I'm currently running Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS but I have experienced these same issues on 18.04.2 LTS.

Here's how I get up and running again.

Note, this solution assumes you running a version of Ubuntu 18.04 and that you have a usable internet connection.

**Step 1**. Open your terminal.

**Step 2**. Run `nordvpn logout`.

**Step 3**. Run `sudo apt purge nordvpn`.

**Step 4**. Run `sudo ls -la /var/lib/` and confirm that the nordvpn directory has been removed from /var/lib/. If it's still there we might run into problems later so go ahead and run `sudo rm -rf ./nordvpn/` to get rid of it.

**Step 5**. Run `sudo apt install nordvpn`. If apt has any issues installing, open up your web browser and navigate to https://nordvpn.com/download/linux/. Go ahead and download the .deb file and install it. Instructions for that process should be available on the download page.

**Step 6**. Run `nordvpn login` and enter your NordVPN credentials.

**Step 7**. Run `nordvpn c`. After a couple of seconds you should see something like *Connecting to United States #XXXX (usXXXX.nordvpn.com)*. If it succeeds you should see something like *You are connected to United States #XXXX (usXXXX.nordvpn.com)*.

And with that you should be good to go.

If you are having this problem on a different version of Ubuntu then I recommend looking for a different solution before trying this one. Good luck!

Comment: It just occurred to me, it's also worth checking your firewall rules. If you are using OpenVPN as your technology then make sure you ALLOW Out connections on port 443. This is simple to do with Gufw Firewall.